# Use of unassigned local variable (Object)

Tags: c#, list, class, object

```
Person tempPerson;

Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of this new person.");
tempPerson.Name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Now their age.");
tempPerson.Age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

peopleList.Add(tempPerson);

RunProgram();
```

At `tempPerson.Name`, the error list displays "Unassigned use of local variable 'tempPerson'. Below is the class where each Person object is created.

```
class Person : PersonCreator
{
    public Person(int initialAge, string initialName)
    {
        initialAge = Age;
        initialName = Name;
    }
    public int Age
    {
        set
        {
            Age = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return Age;
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        set
        {
            Name = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this is a problem. At tempPerson.Age, there is no problem at all. Running the program with only tempPerson.Age brings no errors. Is there a problem with my Person class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`tempPerson` is never initialized to a `Person` object, so it is `null` - any call to any member of the variable will result in a `NullReferenceException`.

You *must* initialize the variable before usage:

```
var tempPerson = new Person();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Managed to get my program working again.

Answer (score 2):

You do not create an object by defining a class or declaring a variable of a class type. You must create an object by calling new on the class, otherwise the variable is initialized with null. Do the following:

```
Person tempPerson = new Person ();

Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of this new person.");
tempPerson.Name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Person class is wrong, it should be:

```
class Person : PersonCreator
{
    public Person(int initialAge, string initialName)
    {
        Age = initialAge;
        Name = initialName;
    }
    public int Age
    {
        set;
        get;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        set;
        get;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable tempPerson is just declared, but not initialized.
You have to call the constructor of Person, but this requires an empty constructor:

```
Person tempPerson = new Person();
```

An other way to solve this, i would implement like the follow:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of this new person.");
string name = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("Now their age.");
string age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

peopleList.Add(new Person(name, age));
```