# Apparently my variable is unassigned?

Tags: c#, list, class, variables, unassigned-variable

```
public Grid (int width, int height, char defaultCharacter) {
    for (int n = 0; n <= height; n++) {
        List<char> aRow;
        for (int i = 0; i <= width; i++) {
            aRow.Add(defaultCharacter);
        }
        this.grid.Add(aRow);
    }
}
```

This is some of my code.
When I run this on Xamarin Studio it gives me an error on these lines saying "Use of unassigned local variable 'aRow'":

- `aRow.Add(defaultCharacter);`
- `this.grid.Add(aRow);`

This function is in a class called Grid, with one variable:

`List<List<char>> grid = new List<List<char>>();`

Any ideas on why this variable is unassigned?

Comment: Because you aren't assigning anything to it? What do you think the value of `aRow` is?

Comment: Good point :P Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: you really didnt have to ask this question. your debugger does not show a red line?

Comment: **possible duplicate** of [Use of unassigned local variable (Object)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193700/use-of-unassigned-local-variable-object?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The variable that you didn't initialize is `aRow`. I think an average person knows that it doesn't have a value. So in order to solve this, you should give a value to it.

As you should already know, we use the `=` operator to give values to variables. So you can instantiate a new instance of `List<char>` like this:

```
aRow = new List<char> ();
```

And you may want to ask why it must have a value before you use it. Because sometimes a variable is `null` (nothing). Let's imagine what will happen if the value of `aRow` is null. `aRow.Add` will cause a `NullReferenceException` because it is *nothing*.

If you don't give the variable a value, the compiler doesn't know whether it is `null` or something else. Thus, it complains.